# How to solve the differential equation , when my initial condition is Infinity

Tags: differential-equations

```
int[r_]=-((557.310989080004 r)/((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + r) (62.8822 + 
r) Sqrt[0.0345106153943703 - ((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + 
  r) (62.8822 + r))/(3000 r)]))
```

> This is the function of r , now next is that I want to solve the differential equation using this function. Before that at my boundary conditions, this whole function vanishes as;

```
int[maxr]=1/0
int[rg]=1/0
```

> maxr=31.0723250284387 and rg=25.57799942210616`

> Next I try to solve the following differential equation via NDsolve

```
sol = NDSolve[{TD'[r] == int[r], TD[maxr] == Infinity}, {TD}, {r,maxr, rg}, Method->"ExplicitRungeKutta"]
```

> But it fails are throws some errors like
> Solve::infc: The system TD==[Infinity] contains an infinite object [Infinity].
> NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.
> Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the ODE is infinity.

You can see this by solving analytically

```
ClearAll[r, TD, k];
intr = -((557.310989080004 r)/((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + r) (62.8822 + 
         r) Sqrt[0.0345106153943703 - ((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + 
              r) (62.8822 + r))/(3000 r)]));
intr = SetPrecision[intr, Infinity];
maxr = SetPrecision[31.0723250284387, Infinity];
rg = SetPrecision[25.57799942210616, Infinity];
sol = TD[r] /. First@DSolve[{TD'[r] == intr}, TD[r], r];
```

Now set up an equation to solve for constant of integration

```
eq = (sol /. r -> maxr) == k;
constant = C[1] /. First@N@Solve[eq, C[1]];
```

Replace the constant found back in the solution

```
sol = sol /. C[1] -> constant;
```

Now let `k` go to infinity, which maps to BC condition that `TD[maxr] == Infinity`

```
Limit[sol, k -> Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This means the solution is

$$
    TD(r)=\infty
$$

You probably want to check you BC are correct.

Comment: Thanks for clarfication. But finally i want to plot TD[r], from maxr to rg . Which should be diverging at maxr and rg. How can that be done

Comment: @ImmySalam  Plot the result of `NDSolve[{TD'[r] == int[r], TD[28] == 0}, TD[r], {r, 25, 32}]`, which goes to `Infinity` at `rg` and `-Infinity` at `rmax`.  Changing the value of `TD[28]` simply moves the whole curve up or down but does not change its shape.